# Proof Verification: Pairwise Independent Events

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Here's the question:

> Let A,B,C be events in the same sample space s.t. every pair of them is independent, and $p(A|B \land C) = p(A)$. Prove that $p(B|A \lor C) = p(B)$.

Here's my proof. I'm not sure if my use of the sum rule is correct - if two events are independent, are they disjoint?

We know that $p(E|F) = \frac{p(E\land F)}{P(F)}$, and if $E,F$ are disjoint, then $P(E \lor F) = P(E) + P(F)$. So:

$$p(B|A \lor C) = \frac{p(B \land (A \lor C))}{p(A\lor C)}$$
$$ = \frac{p((B \land A) \lor (B \land C))}{P(A) + P(C)} = \frac{P(B\land A) + P(B \land C)}{P(A) + P(C)}$$
$$ = \frac{P(B)P(A) + P(B)P(C)}{P(A)+P(C)} = \frac{P(B)(P(A)+P(C))}{P(A)+P(C)}$$
$$ = P(B)$$

Comment: Let $A\cap B=\emptyset$.  Then: $A$ an $B$ are independent $\iff P(A)P(B)=0$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Are you sure that's right?

Comment: Sure.  It just follows from the definition.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ independent $\iff P(A)P(B)=P(A\cap B)$. Now what follows if additionally $A\cap B=\emptyset$?  Your notion of “mutually exclusive” is simply wrong: $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive $\iff A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof in question was erroneous because I was using the fact that:

> if $E,F$ are disjoint, then $P(E \lor F) = P(E) + P(F)$.

Despite the fact that it was nowhere implied that $A,B,C$ are disjoint. Disjoint means to be mutually exclusive, which is not independent at all.

Rather, in this case, I had to use the inclusion-exclusion principle, s.t. $P(E \lor F) = P(E) + P(F) - P(E \land F)$. From that, the rest follows pretty easily.